# zendframework 2 route match is not picking up values

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

i have a router that should provide me with several **params** . However the router is not returning the messId.

**the config:**

```
'messages' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'       => '/message[/:action][/:id][/:senderId][/:messId]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'         => '[0-9]+',
                    'senderId'   => '[0-9]+',
                    'messId'   => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Messages\Controller\MessController',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

**the values returned from the route match:**

```
object(Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\RouteMatch)[346]
  protected 'length' => int 42
  protected 'params' => 
    array (size=4)
      'controller' => string 'Messages\Controller\MessController' (length=36)
      'action' => string 'read-message' (length=12)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'senderId' => string '3' (length=1)
  protected 'matchedRouteName' => string 'messages' (length=15)
```

you will note above that the route match for messId is missing;

**below i my URL**

```
<a href='{$this->url('messages', array('action'=>'read-message','senderId'=>$this->escapeHtml($user['id']), 'messId'=>$this->escapeHtml($user[0]['id']) ))}'>Read Message</a>
```

thank you for your kind assitance.

Comment: What URL is generated by the URL helper? And are you sure that `$user[0]['id']` has a value?

Comment: hi Tim; thanks for responding; the URL is: http://testingzend2/send-message/read-message/7/2 . Also, i checked the values from $user[0]['id'] and it is indeed returning values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is ambiguity in your route. `:id`, `:senderId` and `:messId` are all optional, and they're all numbers. So given a URL like `http://testingzend2/send-message/read-message/7/2` how can ZF know which variable each number relates to?

You either need to make these not optional, or change the route so there's no ambiguity. For example you could do this instead:

```
'route' => '/message[/:action][/id/:id][/senderId/:senderId][/messId/:messId]',
```

Which would give you a URL like `http://testingzend2/send-message/senderId/7/messId/2`

Comment: hey tim. your solition worked. its not very elegant though. how do you mean when you say that i need to mark them as not optional

Comment: The square brackets makes them optional, so if your route was `/message/:action/:id/senderId/:senderId/:mess` then all of the params are required. That would also solve your problem, but you'd have to supply a value for everything (even if it's 0) when building your URLs with the URL helper.